# "redirect_uri is not owned by the application" even valid url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i found many question with same error, but still cant found solution. When i send post request to login (follow this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices)), my request is:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login?access_token=<appid>|<clienttoken>&scope=public_profile,publish_actions&redirect_uri=http://example.com/welcome`

Before this, i have validate my redirect url and it is valid.
[image]

In `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` field in app setting, i add `http://example.com`

I dont know what i miss :(

Answer (score 1):

Cant believe in my eyes, i found the solution. Just go to app setting on facebook developer, add platform, select Website, and add url `http://example.com`. And everything work fine :D